# Google Charts - Creating data from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, google-visualization

I'm having tremendous difficulty trying to reload a google chart using Ajax. I have a input text field with a button that sends the value back to the controller (I'm using Spring), through AJAX. This value is sent back to the view and used as one of the values for the graph.

I appreciate that this is obviously a foolish piece of code, but I am planning to expand it later and want to get this basic functionality correct. I have been at this for nearly one week and am really holding back the sprint which I am working on.

My logic was that I would have a variable called "data2" and the response from the AJAX call would be defined as it. Then the chart would be redrawn with this value. However, nothing loads. The goddaman setOnLoadCallBack is ruining everything I had working before, as when I get something to load with a value, it just deletes it and reloads the original graph!! Please help!

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data2 = 4;
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
        'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]});

        function getData() {
            var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
            $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "profile.html",
            data : "firstname=" + firstname,
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
                data2 = parseInt(response);
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(data2));
                drawChart(data2);
            }
        });
    }

    function drawChart(data2) {
        var data = google.visualization
                .arrayToDataTable([ [ 'Stories', 'Number' ], [ 'Tested', data2 ],
                        [ 'Untested', 10 ] ]);

        var options = {
            title : 'Backlog Items : Test Coverage',
            'width' : 300,
            'height' : 260,
            legend : 'bottom'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document
                .getElementById('storyChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

And here is my Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String processAJAXRequest(@RequestParam(value = "firstname")String firstName){
    return firstName;
    }
```

This controller works fine as I am getting a string response of exactly what I require.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in use of setOnLoadCallBack. It should not be inside a success callback of AJAX call. It is basically a request to load chart library and upon completion doing something. I would suggest something along these lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data2 = 4;
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
        'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]});

    function getData() {
         var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
         $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "profile.html",
            data : "firstname=" + firstname,
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
                data2 = parseInt(response);
                drawChart(data2);
            }
        });
    }

    function drawChart(data2) {
        var data = google.visualization
                .arrayToDataTable([ [ 'Stories', 'Number' ], [ 'Tested', data2 ],
                        [ 'Untested', 10 ] ]);

        var options = {
            title : 'Backlog Items : Test Coverage',
            'width' : 300,
            'height' : 260,
            legend : 'bottom'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document
                .getElementById('storyChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        window.setTimeout(getData, 10000);
    }

   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(data2));
</script>
```

It is just a sample where chart is loaded when chart library is loaded and then after ten seconds getData is called to retrieve data and update chart. Obviously you could want some other way to trigger update of the chart then timeout (I don't know you use case, maybe on button click?)

Comment: No graphs drawn with this, either.